# Help finding historical data for velocity of money (M1 or M2) for any country except USA

Tags: money

Can anyone point me to a data set of money velocity for at least 20 years back for any other country than the US?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to expand your definition of money, then yes, and easily: You can get [broad money measures](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/FM.LBL.BMNY.GD.ZS?view=chart) (M2, M3 and M4) as a percent of nominal GDP ($\frac{M}{PY} \times  100%$) from the World Bank for several decades for many countries (mileage will vary depending on particular country).

Just divide by 100 and invert.  By the quantity theory of money,  $V = \frac{PY}{M}$, Bob's your uncle.  Note that this will underestimate V compared to values reported by e.g. the Federal Reserve, because M includes M3 and M4.